# MPMoviePlayerViewController Distorting UISplitViewController on iPad in Landscape

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm playing a video using the MPMoviePlayerViewController on the iPad, presented on a UISplitViewController.  The movie player presents perfectly, and rotates to landscape and portrait with no issues.  When I tap "Done" to close the video, the UISplitViewController slides in from the bottom correctly, but when the iPad is held in landscape the UISplitViewController's width seems to be set to the standard portrait width, centered in the landscape view with black bars on both the left and righthand sides.

I've seen this problem before, and the issue was the viewController that was having another view controller pushed onto it wasn't supporting landscape orientations in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation.  I know that is not the case in this issue.

Here is the code:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpc = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[mpc setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
mpc.view.frame = viewController.view.frame;
mpc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[viewController presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpc];
[mpc release];
```